# What is minimum IOPS for AWS EC2 General Purpose SSD (gp2)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

A while ago I read, that you get 3 IOPS per GB for gp2 SSD volumes. For example, that would be 24 IOPS for 8 GB volume. Now I read the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) and it states:

> ... Between a minimum of 100 IOPS (at 33.33 GiB and below) and a
>   maximum of 10,000 IOPS (at 3,334 GiB and above), baseline performance
>   scales linearly at 3 IOPS per GiB of volume size. A gp2 volume can
>   range in size from 1 GiB to 16 TiB.

So if I create 1 GB volume, will I be capped to 3 IOPS, or 100 IOPS?

UPDATE: In the official AWS forum someone from Amazon talks about 24 IOPS for 8 GB drive, but this was in 2014. What has changed since then? Limit is lifted? (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162482)

Comment: The docs you quote give the answer. "at 33.33 GiB and below"

Comment: Yes, but I remember reading in the official AWS forum, that it is capped. Is this recent change, or wrong documentation? Example here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162482

Comment: That thread is from 2 years ago. Things may have changed, docs have been known to be wrong before. But to be sure, you'll have to contact AWS support for up-to-date information.

Comment: @MattHouser, they do not have free support, so this is not an option for me. I hoped to get the answer from real world experience... or at least some info, that the previous limit is lifted.

Comment: @MarisB. This is Q&A not free support too.

Comment: The forums you linked to is AWS free support. You can ask them there.

Comment: @Iain, I am not asking for free support. Sorry, if you misunderstood me.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. When you are creating volume from EC2 Management Console, it allows you to specify the size in GiBs. It also calculates and shows IOPS for the newly created volume.

If you specify volume size above 30 GiB, it shows IOPS by using the formula:

```
your_specified_size * 3 = IOPS
```

**If you specify size smaller than 30 GiB, it still shows 100 IOPS.** Even for 1 GiB volume, it shows 100 IOPS.